# Questions for second person

Tags: grammar, questions

Hi I'm trying understand these phrases if I use do for ask... e.g.: Do you have a car? Or Have you a car? Another example: Do you've seen Pedro? Or Have you seen Pedro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are tricky because they are different.

The common way to ask the first question is, "Do you have a car?" Your alternative, "Have you a car?", is acceptable but rarely used.

But the second question should be, "Have you seen Pedro?" Do NOT say "Do you have seen ...", that's just wrong.

The difference is that you are using the word "have" with two different definitions. In the first example, "have" is used as the primary verb with the meaning "to hold or possess". But in the second example, it's a helping verb modifying the tense of "to see": "Do you see Pedro?" Present tense. The seeing is happening right now. "Have you seen Pedro?" Present perfect. The seeing happened at some unspecified time.

In English, questions almost always begin with some "question word", generally "who", "what", "where", "why", "when", "do", "is", or "have". We don't see "You see Pedro?"; we say, "Do you see Pedro?" You need to add the extra "do" there to make it a question. But when the question is in a perfect tense, you don't need an extra word, so it's just, "Have you seen Pedro?" and NO "Do you have seen Pedro?" or some other variation.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different pairs of sentences.  Either of the first two is correct, but you will see the second one more often in the UK than in the US.  Of the second two, the first one is incorrect.  We don't use "do" as an auxiliary in the composite past tense.  This will be clearer if we remove the contraction from the sentence: "Do you have seen Pedro?" is more obviously wrong.  Now, have a look at these:

> Did you see Pedro?
> I saw Pedro.
>
> Have you seen Pedro?
> I have seen Pedro.

So, we use "do" in the simple past, but we already have an auxiliary verb to reverse in the composite past, so we don't add another.